# Thermostat with an external transformer

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to hook up a Vine TJ-610B-W WiFi thermostat to my heater. The original thermostat had only 2 wires, hooked to R and W, none hiding in the wall. I plan to use an external transformer for power. The problem comes when hooking up the new wires, I now have 4 wires and all I read say to hook the original 2 to R and W, then from the transformer to C and either RH or RC. Problem is the new thermostat only has and R. What I have is "R" "G" "W" "Y" "C" "W2" "..." "O/B-Y2"

Thank You

Comment: What sort of heater is your thermostat hooked up to? Is re-running the thermostat wire an option?

Comment: That is an option, right now there are just 2 wires coming from the heater, I would need to add a third wire for C to what I have now? It is a Tempstar< I don't have the model # handy. Thanks.

Comment: Is it a central heating furnace, or a wall heater of some sort?

Comment: It's a central heat furnace.